# How to call a Jquery method on page load or page refresh in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a new JQuery widget for my project and I need to call that method on page load.

Here is the widget sample:

```
(function($){
   $.widget("mywidget", {
     options: {

     },
    _create: function(){
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
       url: "/api/1.0/getdata",
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json",

       success: function(arg) {
        //will be inserting the details from the json call into the <div>
        var data = arg;
       },
        error: function(resp){
        }
     });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is how I am trying to make the call to the widget:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log("show my widget");
   $("#div").mywidget();
});
```

Here is the HTML I am trying to load for my widget:

```
<div id="div">
  <p>Welcome to the newly created JQuery widget</p>
</div>
```

But when I do this nothing gets called, neither is the URL called, from which I am trying to access the data to show in my message nor the `<div>`. Any idea how can i access the widget on page load?

Comment: Is the `console.log("show my widget");` outputting anything to the console?

Comment: no..it does not show the log as well, but in the console,when i run the widget, it gets loaded...

Comment: Your `document.ready` call is missing closing parentheses and semicolon.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Because there's a syntax error at the end of your `$(document).ready` call. (You're missing a `);` after the `}`)

Comment: For clarity's sake, I modified the snippet not to have those obvious errors, now @user1234 based off that... do you have any issues that continue to arise?

Comment: Also my guess towards why your code is not working is because of closure, correct me if I am wrong but, is calling `$("#div").mywidget();` from `$(document).ready` not going to work because `mywidget` exists in a separate scope.. meaning within `(function($){/...})();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax errors aside, using the latest stable jQuery UI I had to include a namespace in my widget name. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruzqauyL/) with your code working. Note that it will correctly output an error attempting to hit `/api/1.0/getdata`.

If this solution doesn't work in your setup, ensure that the widget initialization code is being run before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your document ready is just missing brackets..
try -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log("show my widget");
   $("#div").mywidget();
});
```

Comment: Sorry thats just the typo while writing the code here, but i have the correct syntax and it still doesnt work as required...